# How to use meteor stream on native apps?

Tags: android, meteor, sockjs

I'm trying to build a chat application using `Meteor 1.4.1`. For events like notifying a user when another user is typing, I've to implement using [Meteor Streamer](https://github.com/RocketChat/meteor-streamer). It works fine with client app on the browser but integrating it on Android / iOS.

How can I make this to work with native apps as well?
OR
How this type of functionality should be configured along with meteor and its native apps?

**Update**
On server-side I've declared it as:

```
const streamer = new Meteor.Streamer('notify-user');
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  streamer.allowRead('all');
  streamer.allowWrite('all');
}
```

On App-side, I'm using `Android DDP` [Delight-im](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-DDP) library which doesn't have any methods to call/emit or listen to stream events.

How do I fire an event on `notify-user` stream from the Native Android app?

Comment: Hi, have you made it to work?

Answer (score 0):

This should work on Android or IOS, in fact you shouldn't have to do anything special. What problems are you seeing?

Comment: I've updated the Question, Problem I'm facing is in the implementation at client side (Android / iOS). 
Meteor DDP clients are providing methods to call `methods` and  `subscribe` to publications only.

Comment: I haven't used the Delight-im library, so it's hard to say. You might try https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-streams - it might work better.

Comment: For Arunoda's Meteor streamer: Project development status is inactive, also  `build:error` on github page. Is working fine with `Meteor 1.4.1`?

Comment: Again If use this one, I need to call `chatStream = new Meteor.Stream('chat');` on the client side, how will I create `chatStream` object in android app?